# Fillna based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe, how to fillna col2 based on col1? Here fillna with 10, I have multiple col1 values but each one only has 1 corresponding col2 value or it is nan.

```
col1 col2
 A    Nan
 A    10
```

Comment: do you mind sharing more rows  - it may be possible to achieve your goal using ``ffill`` or ``bfill``

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `fillna` by `groupby` and `transform`

```
df.col2.fillna(df.groupby('col1').col2.transform('first'), inplace=True)
```